# Problems with SUNAT bill service integration with PHP

Tags: php, service

I tried to use the SUNAT BillService "beta" web service in order to test my app. I'm sending dummy bill/invoice. The SUNAT guidelines are given on below URL:
http://orientacion.sunat.gob.pe/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1899:informacion-de-interes&catid=259:factura-electronica-desde-sistemas-contribuyente&Itemid=468

And the "beta" serive is:
https://www.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpgem-beta/billService

This service required to send a dummy credentials and an XML file packed in ZIP format. I did it but with some problems, receiving an error "0101": "Incorrect security header"

I'm using SoapUI with the following information for billService:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.sunat.gob.pe" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>20505819340MODDATOS</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>moddatos</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:sendBill>
        <fileName>20505819340-01-F001-1.zip</fileName>
        <contentFile>cid:20505819340-01-F001-1.zip</contentFile>
    </ser:sendBill>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Where: MODDATOS is the dummy credentials for the service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this incident taking a different way.
First, the service can't be tested with SOAP tools, like SoapUI for example.
Second, with Php, the zip file in byte array couldn't be sent because some rare reason (maybe the Php's poor support on attachments over soap protocol).

So I changed the language to C#, now I could test a dummy file to the soap service, I had some (solved) problems, but I receive a succesfull response from the service.

Answer (score 0):

This into SOAP Header:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-14736896964491689917771">
                <wsse:Username>[RUC]MODDATOS</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MODDATOS</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        ...
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```